# PCB clearance on eagle to make coplanar lines

Tags: eaglecad, clearance

I need to define a clearance between my signal path and souronding ground of 0.16mm in Eagle PCB layout. 
I tried to setup the "isolate" at 0.16 and do "ratsnets" but it keeps the same distance as before = 0.2mm. How can I change from 0.2 to 0.16?

Answer (score 2):

Assign a class to both signals and specify a clearance between them.  Copper pours will respect this rule.

Type "class" in Eagle's command line to bring up the class dialog and create classes and specify clearances.

[image]